# using Oracle REGEXP_INSTR to find exact word

Tags: regex, oracle

I want to return the following position from the strings using `REGEXP_INSTR`.

I am looking for the word **car** with exact match in the following strings.

```
car,care,oscar - 1
care,car,oscar - 6
oscar,care,car - 12
```

something like

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('car,care,oscar', 'car', 1, 1) "REGEXP_INSTR" FROM DUAL;
```

I am not sure what kind of escape operators to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution is to surround the source string and search string with commas and find the position using INSTR.

```
SELECT INSTR(',' || 'car,care,oscar' || ',', ',car,') "INSTR" FROM DUAL;
```

Example:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/32722)

```
with x(y) as (
SELECT 'car,care,oscar' from dual union all
SELECT 'care,car,oscar' from dual union all
SELECT 'oscar,care,car' from dual union all
SELECT 'car' from dual union all
SELECT 'cart,care,oscar' from dual
)
select y, ',' || y || ',' , instr(',' || y || ',',',car,')
from x


|               Y |       ','||Y||',' | INSTR(','||Y||',',',CAR,') |
|-----------------|-------------------|----------------------------|
|  car,care,oscar |  ,car,care,oscar, |                          1 |
|  care,car,oscar |  ,care,car,oscar, |                          6 |
|  oscar,care,car |  ,oscar,care,car, |                         12 |
|             car |             ,car, |                          1 |
| cart,care,oscar | ,cart,care,oscar, |                          0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query handles all scenarios. It returns the starting position if the string begins with `car,` or the whole string is just `car`. It returns the starting position + 1 if `,car,` is found or if the string ends with `,car` to account for the comma.

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('car,care,oscar', '^car,|^car$') THEN REGEXP_INSTR('car,care,oscar', '^car,|^car$', 1, 1)
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('car,care,oscar', ',car,|,car$') THEN REGEXP_INSTR('car,care,oscar', ',car,|,car$', 1, 1)+1
    ELSE 0
  END  "REGEXP_INSTR"
FROM DUAL;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/32718)</kbd> with the various possibilities

Answer (score 0):

I like Noel his answer as it gives a very good performance! Another way around is by creating separate rows from a character separated string:
pm.nodes = 'a;b;c;d;e;f;g'

```
(select regexp_substr(pm.nodes,'[^;]+', 1, level) 
   from dual 
connect by regexp_substr(pm.nodes, '[^;]+', 1, level) is not null)
```